# Search with asciifolding and UTF-8 characters in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am indexing all the names on a web page with characters with accents like "José". I want to be able to search the this name with "Jose" and "José".

How should I set up my index mapping and analyzer(s) for a simple index with one field "name"?

I set up an analyzer for the name field like this:

```
"analyzer": {
  "folding": {
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
   }
 }
```

But it folds all accents into ASCII equivalents and ignores the accent when indexing the "é". I want the "é" char to be in the index and I want to be able to search "José" with either "José" or "Jose".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to preserve the original token with the accent. To achieve that you need to redefine your own `asciifolding` token filter, like this:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "folding" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "my_ascii_folding"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "my_ascii_folding" : {
                    "type" : "asciifolding",
                    "preserve_original" : true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "folding"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that, both tokens `jose` and `josé` will be indexed and searchable

Answer (score 0):

This is what I can think of to resolve the folding problem with diacritical marks:

```
Analyzer used:
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the mapping to be used:

```
mappings used:
    {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type":           "string",
          "analyzer":       "standard",
          "fields": {
            "folded": {
              "type":       "string",
              "analyzer":   "folding"
            }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

- The title field uses the standard analyzer and will contain the original word with diacritics in place.
- The title.folded field uses the folding analyzer, which strips the diacritical marks.

**Below is the search query I will use:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "most_fields",
      "query":    "esta loca",
      "fields": [ "title", "title.folded" ]
    }
  }
}
```